# How do i execute a callback in a jQuery Plugin code

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

This may sound really like a newbie .. But i used the jQuery Boilerplate on this page - http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/ and created a plugin. Everything works fine, except now i want to add a callback. I want to execute this -

```
$.Alerter({'message':'this is a test','onSuccess':function(data) { alert(data); } });
```

The onSuccess is a callback function which is added to the defaults.

My question is – how do i send the output to the onSuccess. I want it to return back a TRUE or FALSE value after certain steps have been executed in the init()

Comment: a possible alternative would be to add another property to the Alerter class in which Alerter.init() saves the result, which then can be read by the calling scope.

Comment: Why not just `var stub = plugin.onSuccess&&plugin.onSuccess(variableName);`? Where variableName stores previously evaluated value.

Comment: @Bora can u provide a example .. i think ur method could work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
plugin.result = null;

plugin.init = function() {
    // do stuff
    ...
    // save _result in public variable result 
    plugin.result = _result;
}
```

If you are writing this plugin for dom operations, you could also use it like `plugin.data('result',_result);`

Since I don't know anything else I can't give further insight.
Hope this will help you.